# Importing Another Scenes Audio in Sequencer

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

Blender 2.93/Windows10

I have multiple scenes animated and ***synced to their own  audio clips( imported in their respective Sequencers).***

However,on importing all these individual scene into a Main Scene (say a Sequencer_Scene),
***the Sequencer_Scene doesn't import and play the audio of these individual scenes***(but shows the 3d_Camera output fine).

Is it possible to import another Scenes Audio in Sequencer_Scene?

Also,is there a way to play the Audio from the Sequencer_Scene in other scenes(for animation syncing)?

Comment: I had that problem before and never found a way around it. It seems like when it comes to audio, Blender only ever considers the current scene and nothing else.

Comment: I have raised an issue :https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/NOXK/?sorting=hot